# Claimed as a dependent in 2019, but not in 2018. Will I receive the COVID-19 stimulus payment?

Tags: united-states, taxes, covid-19, stimulus

2019 taxes i was filed as an adult dependant for the first tims in 15 years. I have every other year filed my own taxes. Will I qualify for a stimulus check or a $1200 refundable credit on my 2020 taxes? In 2018 i filed my own taxes and could not be claimed as a dependent. I don't understand why I would be excluded since they have said they would go by a person's 2018 return if they have not yet filed for 2019. People who made too much money in 2019 and have not yet filed for 2019 are using their AGI on their 2018 returns to qualify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, you are correct, the IRS will use 2019 data first, and then 2018 data if that is not available. However, you were put down on *someone else's* return for 2019 so you have technically filed. Therefore they will not look at 2018 and you will not get the stimulus check in April 2020 (the IRS might still send it to you if they do decide to look at 2018, but I doubt they would bother).

The person claiming you for 2019 will also *not* get the $500 for dependents since you are not a child under 17 years of age.

The only for sure way you will get the stimulus check is if you file independently for 2020 and *no one is able to claim you as a dependent*. Note that it does not depend on whether you get claimed or not. If someone *could* claim you, you are not eligible for the stimulus, even if they don't actually claim you.

The "check" is really just an advance on a credit for tax year 2020, [see here](https://money.com/stimulus-check-advance-tax-refund/) and the [text of the bill](https://www.congress.gov/bill/116th-congress/house-bill/748), section 2101:

> there shall be allowed as a credit against the tax imposed by
>   subtitle A for the first taxable year beginning in 2020

So, assuming you will meet the requirements for 2020, you'll just get the credit after you file your taxes in 2021.

Comment: "However, you were put down on someone else's return for 2019 so you have technically filed." I disagree with this. Whether you have filed a tax return and whether someone has claimed you as a dependent are independent things.

Comment: @user102008 While that's true in most cases, I would expect the IRS to just look for *any* data on 2019. They search for the OP"s SSN and find they are a dependent on someone else's return. No need to look back to 2018. If you have a source that states otherwise I will gladly edit or delete my answer.

Comment: @Nosjack Regarding my eligibility to receive the stimulus as a tax credit when filing my 2020 taxes, how certain are you of this? I am curenntly employed and won't be eligible to be claimed as a dependent for this year, so I'd like to find out now if I can expect to receive this as a tax credit next year. Every news source simply says that dependents aren't eligible to receive a stimulus check.

Comment: @StevenMilner See here https://money.com/stimulus-check-advance-tax-refund/ - The check is an advance on a 2020 tax credit. The text of the bill is here https://www.congress.gov/bill/116th-congress/senate-bill/3548/text under section 2101 - note that the check is "for the first taxable year beginning in 2020". Also updated my answer.

Comment: @Nosjack I noticed that the bill you cited was not the version of the CARES Act that was signed into law. This is it: https://www.congress.gov/bill/116th-congress/house-bill/748 . I am looking at sec 2201 of the bill and noticed this part: (d) Eligible individual.—For purposes of this section, the term ‘eligible individual’ means any individual other than—

“(2) any individual with respect to whom a deduction under section 151 is allowable to another taxpayer for a taxable year beginning in the calendar year in which the individual’s taxable year begins ... What do you think of that part?

Comment: @StevenMilner I am not a lawyer, but that section seems to be the part that says you're not eligible if someone can claim you as a dependent. Section 151 has to do with personal exemptions (not application with the recent Tax Cut and Jobs Act). Basically, if someone can claim your personal exemption (and therefore is claiming you as a dependent) you're not eligible.